# Adding Scrollview covers up toolbar

Tags: android, uiscrollview

[Without Scrollview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBCEQ.png)

I need the white space below the toolbar in the image above to be in a scrollview. But adding a scroll view results in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gZED.png):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_newg"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"

                app:layout_collapseMode="none"
                app:elevation="0dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">



                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="32dp"
                    android:paddingStart="32dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="40dp"
                    android:paddingRight="16dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="16dp">

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/entry_home_TIL"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="0dp">

                        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText

                            android:textSize="27sp"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:inputType="textAutoComplete|textCapWords|textAutoCorrect"
                            android:id="@+id/entry_home" />
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/entry_away_TIL"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp">
                        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText

                            android:textSize="27sp"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:inputType="textAutoComplete|textCapWords|textAutoCorrect"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/entry_away" />
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/entry_tourney_title_TIL"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp">
                        <EditText
                            android:hint="Tournament"
                            android:textSize="27sp"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:inputType="textAutoComplete|textCapWords|textAutoCorrect"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/entry_tourney_title" />
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/newGameFields"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_event_black_24dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_event_black_24dp"
            android:drawablePadding="31dp"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingStart="20dp"
            android:paddingEnd="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:text="Time"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/dateText"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:id="@+id/timeText"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_clock_black_24dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_clock_black_24dp"
            android:drawablePadding="31dp"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="30dp"
            android:paddingStart="30dp"
            android:paddingEnd="30dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />


    </RelativeLayout>

        <View style="@style/Divider_Horz"/>

        <EditText
            android:hint="Location"
            android:background="@null"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_place_black_24dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_place_black_24dp"
            android:drawablePadding="31dp"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingStart="20dp"
            android:paddingEnd="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:inputType="textAutoComplete|textCapWords|textAutoCorrect"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/entry_location" />

        <View style="@style/Divider_Horz"/>

        <EditText
            android:hint="Add starters"
            android:background="@null"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_people_black_24dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_people_black_24dp"
            android:drawablePadding="31dp"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingStart="20dp"
            android:paddingEnd="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:inputType="textAutoComplete|textCapWords|textAutoCorrect"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/entry_starters" />

        <View style="@style/Divider_Horz"/>

        <EditText
            android:hint="Add note"
            android:background="@null"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_short_text_black_24dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_short_text_black_24dp"
            android:drawablePadding="31dp"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingStart="20dp"
            android:paddingEnd="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:inputType="textAutoComplete|textCapWords|textAutoCorrect"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/entry_notes" />



    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

If you have ever used the google calendar app when adding an event I would like it to be like that.

Here is the relevant fragment code:

```
 import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

import com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class NewGame extends Fragment {

    //private static final String TAG = "AKDialogFragment";


    EditText entryAway, entryHome;
    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener2;
    private static final int[] EDITTEXT_IDS = {
            R.id.entry_home,
            R.id.entry_away
    };


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {



        FloatingActionMenu fab = (FloatingActionMenu) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.material_design_android_floating_action_menu);
        fab.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_new_game, container, false);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_newg);
        toolbar.setTitle("");

        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ActionBar actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_close_white_24px);
        }

        return rootView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        final TimePickerDialog timePicker;

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM d, yyyy");
        String formattedDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
        ((TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.dateText)).setText(formattedDate);

        setTime12Hour(hour,minute);

        TextView textViewDate = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.dateText);

        textViewDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Do something in response to button click
                DialogFragment picker = new DatePickerFragment();
                picker.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
            }
        });
        TextView textViewTime = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.timeText);
        textViewTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Do something in response to button click
                showTimePickerDialog(v);
            }
        });
        String team = "West Albany";
        EditText eTHome = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.entry_home);
        TextInputLayout eTHomeTil = (TextInputLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.entry_home_TIL);
        EditText eTAway = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.entry_away);
        TextInputLayout eTAwayTil = (TextInputLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.entry_away_TIL);
        switch (this.getTag()) {

            case "home":
                eTAwayTil.setHint("Away");
                eTHome.setText(team);
                break;

            case "away":
                eTHomeTil.setHint("Home");
                eTAway.setText(team);
                break;

            case "tourney":

                eTAwayTil.setHint("White");
                eTHomeTil.setHint("Dark");
                break;

            case "scout":
                eTHomeTil.setHint("Home");
                eTAwayTil.setHint("Away");
                break;

        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        menu.clear();
        getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_ak, menu);
    }
```

Thank you guys!

Comment: why NestedScrollView?have you tried replacing it with just ScrollView?

Comment: Within `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout` you have to use `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView`

Answer (score 0):

try removing android:fitsSystemWindows from AppBarLayout and add to NestedScrollView marginTop the height of AppBarLayout(you can calculate this height inside your Fragment, for example try setting marginTop to 200dp)